# Flexbox image grid that fills the entire width and wraps

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create an image grid that fills the entire space -- those images come in random sizes. I got a basic version of this working in my first example.

But I need to add more functionality, and to wrap those images into `div`s. I can't get that to work. You can checkout the second example.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v1swdLgt/.

Would you have any idea as to how I can solve this problem?

Thank you!!

```
<div class="thatworks grid">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/40/30?random" alt="something"/>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/35/30?random" alt="something"/>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/42/30?random" alt="something"/>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/31/30?random" alt="something"/>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/44/30?random" alt="something"/>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/32/30?random" alt="something"/>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/22/30?random" alt="something"/>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/40/30?random" alt="something"/>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/35/30?random" alt="something"/>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/42/30?random" alt="something"/>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/31/30?random" alt="something"/>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/44/30?random" alt="something"/>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/32/30?random" alt="something"/>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/22/30?random" alt="something"/>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/42/30?random" alt="something"/>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/31/30?random" alt="something"/>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/44/30?random" alt="something"/>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/32/30?random" alt="something"/>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/22/30?random" alt="something"/>
</div>

<div class="doesntworks grid">
  <div>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/40/30?random" alt="something"/> 
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/35/30?random" alt="something"/>
  </div>
  <div>
   <img src="https://unsplash.it/42/30?random" alt="something"/> 
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/31/30?random" alt="something"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/44/30?random" alt="something"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/32/30?random" alt="something"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/22/30?random" alt="something"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/40/30?random" alt="something"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/35/30?random" alt="something"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/42/30?random" alt="something"/>
  </div>
</div>


.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.thatworks img {
  flex: 1;
}

.doesntworks div {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you use the `background-image` property on your `divs`, as opposed to having `img` tags inside of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `display: flex` to your divs and add the same style to `img` as you added in your working grid:

CSS

```
.thatworks img, .doesntworks img {
    flex: 1;
}
.doesntworks div {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
}
```

DEMO

https://jsfiddle.net/v1swdLgt/1/

Comment: Oh duh. Thank you!! :)